# rails use form input value before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-input, before-save, lov

I have a form in rails with input values, and 1 of the values is a LOV (List of Values) and a second input field is also a LOV but depends on the input of the other field.
The input value of the first field is not saved in between. So I need to use that field value before it is saved.
So, the example:
I choose a company from the list of values of all companies for the field supplier, the second field supplier_address will be a LOV with all the addresses of that company, so the LOV of the second field is dependent on the value chosen in the first field, company.

What I tried:

```
  def new
    @purchase_requisition = PurchaseRequisition.new
    @purchase_requisition.number = find_next_user_value("Purchase_Requisition")
    #@purchase_requisition.supplier_address_id =  PurchaseRequisition.new.purchase_requisition_params[:supplier_id]
    @purchase_requisition = PurchaseRequisition.new(purchase_requisition_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      @purchase_requisition.supplier_address_id = PurchaseRequisition.new.purchase_requisition_params[:supplier_id]
    end
  end
```

but I still get the error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: purchase_requisition

Can someone please help me?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering isn't being caused by the code you've provided. You're probably using strong parameters and have a method like this:

```
def purchase_requisition_params
   params.require(:purchase_requisition).permit(# some list of attributes #)
end
```

The problem is that `params[:purchase_requisition]` doesn't exist. Probably because the `form_for` in your view isn't referencing a `purchase_requisition` object. Try adding `as:` to your `form_for` to send your params under that param key:

```
form_for @requisition, as: :purchase_requisition, ....
```

Otherwise, you'll have to post more details about your view and controller to help isolate the issue you're having.

Also, in your controller code you want:

```
PurchaseRequisition.new(purchase_requisition_params[:supplier_id])
```

Instead of:

```
PurchaseRequisition.new.purchase_requisition_params[:supplier_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing, all of your parameters belong to the same object (there isn't any nested attribute), this can be what you are looking for:

```
  def purchase_requisition_params
    params.require(:purchase_requisition).permit(:org_id, :document_type, :number, :supplier_id, :supplier_address_id, :partner_id, :project_id, :construction_site_id, :purchase_order_date, :expected_receiving_date, :promised_receiving_date, :supplier_order_number, :supplier_shipping_number, :supplier_invoice_number, :currency, :status) ##you don't need id here
  end
```